# Refreshing ArrayAdapter onResume [notifyDataSetChanged() not working]

Tags: android, refresh, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a contact list app using Fragments where one frag is a list of names in the contact list and the other is the rest of the details.

Here is the class that displays the list of names

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ContactStorage contactStorage = new ContactStorage();

public final static String TAG = "FRAGMENTS";
private MainActivity parent;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();

String array[];

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
    parent = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    entries = contactStorage.getContactListNames();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, entries);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter created");
    array = contactStorage.getContactDetails();
    return v;

}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    entries = contactStorage.getContactListNames();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG, "List Frag Resumed");

}
}
```

The problem I am having is that the ArrayAdapter does not refresh on resume.

When the screen is rotated, its fine as onCreateView() is ran again, but I need it to refresh onResume. I have looked over this site loads and found nothing but "use notifyDataSetChanged()" which doesn't work.

Comment: Well, what do you expect? You're retrieving the `entries` but aren`t re-building your `adapter`. Move the two lines `entires =` and `adapter =` from `onCreate()` to `onResume()` (you should only do that once), forget about `entries =` and `notify` in `onResume()` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @ClassStacker - Still the same problem. Doesn't refresh the list until the screen is rotated.

Comment: Umm yes sorry, you'll also have to do the setListAdapter() there.

Comment: @ClassStacker - I can see how that would work, but would that be more of a "hacky" way around it?

Comment: My suggestion is equivalent to the one you accepted. There's nothing "hacky" about it. It's just that the `clear()`/`addAll()` approach is slower than just throwing away the whole thing _en bloc_.

Comment: @ClassStacker - So your version is an optimised version of the below solution?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

the issue you're having is that you're overwriting the entries reference and it's not getting changed on the adapter. Here's how you can fix this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    entries.clear();
    entries.addAll(contactStorage.getContactListNames());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG, "List Frag Resumed");

}
```

this is a common mistake to make, it's caused because when you first create a list (in memory) and your `entries` field points to that, you then tell the `adapter` to look at that memory location when you create it, but `onResume` you create a new list in memory (when you get the contact list names again) and you tell entries to point to that new list in memory, what you need to do is replace the entries in the original list with the entries in the new list, that way the `adapter` will still reference the same list.

Comment: Perfect! I knew there was something to do with '.add()' but I couldnt get a clear answer on the topic. Thank you very much!

Comment: I added a better explanation about the issue too. another way you could do it with your ArrayAdapter is on resume `adapter.clear();` then `adapter.addAll(contactStorage.getContactListNames());` and just forget the entries field all together.

Comment: Clearing the list and adding updated elements again is throwing ConcurrentModificationException in latest android as ArrayAdapter is also trying to read the list. Clear Adapter and adapter.addAll() is working fine. kudos @Eluvatar

Answer (score 5):

**notifyDataSetChanged()** won't work for you. Reasons why

***Your adapter loses reference to your list. When you first initialize the Adapter it takes a reference of your arrayList and pass to its superclass. But if you reinitialize your existing arrayList it losts the reference hence the communication channel with Adapter :(.***

Always creating and adding a new list to the Adapter. Do like this:

1. Initialize the arrayList while declaring globally.
2. Add List to the adapter directly with out checking null and empty
   condition. Set the adapter to the list directly(don't check for any
   condition). Adapter gives you the guarantee that wherever you are
   changes the data of arrayList it will take care, but never loose the
   reference.
3. Add data to the arrayList Every time(if your data is completely new
   than you can call adapter.clear() and arrayList.clear() before
   actually adding data to the list) but don't set the adapter i.e If
   the new data is populated in the arrayList than just
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

***Keep trust to Documentations***